# Is there any way to get notifications in process when a thread changes state?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Is there any way to get notifications in process when a thread changes state? I am writing a program that monitors thread state changes. I can poll each thread frequently but I would prefer something more reactive.

Comment: Have you looked at [Guarded Blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html)?

Answer (score 1):

yes, use `conditional variable`, here is an example:

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.*;
public class CubbyHole2 {
    private int contents;
    private boolean available = false;  // this is your state
    private Lock aLock = new ReentrantLock(); // state must be protected by lock
    private Condition condVar = aLock.newCondition(); // instead of polling, block on a condition

    public int get(int who) {
        aLock.lock();  
        try {
            // first check state
            while (available == false) {
                try {
                    // if state not match, go to sleep
                    condVar.await(); 
                } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
            }
            // when status match, do someting

            // change status
            available = false;
            System.out.println("Consumer " + who + " got: " +
                                contents);
            // wake up all sleeper than wait on this condition
            condVar.signalAll();  
        } finally {
            aLock.unlock();
            return contents;
        }
    }

    public void put(int who, int value) {
                    aLock.lock();
    try {
        while (available == true) {
            try {
                condVar.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        }
        contents = value;
        available = true;
        System.out.println("Producer " + who + " put: " +
                            contents);
        condVar.signalAll();
        } finally {
            aLock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `while (available == true)` and `while (available == false)` you should use the idiomatic `while(available)` and `while(!available)`…

Answer (score 0):

The code you thread runs needs to be injected with code to make a call back which the state changes.  You could do this by changing the code as @宏杰李 suggests or injecting the code with `Instrumentation` however polling the threads is likely to be simplest.

NOTE: The thread's state only tells you it's desired state from a JVM point of view. It doesn't show you

- is it blocked on a blocking IO operation?
- has it been context switched
- has it been interrupted by the OS or the BIOS
- has it been stopped for GC or code replacement
- is it waiting for a lock on a static initialiser block. e.g. if it blocked waiting for the class to initialise it says it is RUNNING.

BTW Even the OS polls CPUs to see what they are doing, typically 100 times per second.

Comment: All are fine, but that last one, static initialization, I hadn't realized. Are you saying that if a thread is started in a static initializer, it will always block until the class initialization is complete?

Comment: @VictorGrazi if a thread is blocked waiting for another thread to finish the static block it appears as RUNNING when really it's waiting.

Comment: @VictorGrazi also, if a static block starts a thread and waits for it to finish it can easily deadlock in a way which isnt easily apparent.